# Making good column names R

Tags: r, naming-conventions

I read a table from Microsoft Access using RODBC. Some of the variables had a name with a space in it.

R has no problem with it but I do.
I cannot find out how to specify the space

```
names(alltime)
 [1] "ID"            "LVL7"          "Ref Pv No"     "Ref Pv Name"   "DOS"           "Pt Last Name"  "Pt First Name" "MRN"           "CPT"           "CPT Desc"      "DxCd1"         "DxCd2"         "DxCd3"         "DxCd4"        
[15] "DOE"
```

But what do I do if I want to do something such as this

```
> alltime[grep("MIDDLE EAR EXPLORE",alltime$CPT Desc,]
Error: unexpected symbol in "alltime[grep("MIDDLE EAR EXPLORE",alltime$CPT Desc"
```

Comment: You're missing a close bracket in your alltime command. Does it change anything? Also, would `alltime$"CPT Desc"` work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Also see `make.names`

Answer (score 6):

You can quote the column name, e.g.

```
alltime$'CPT Desc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a pair of backticks: `` alltime$`CPT Desk` ``

And also there is a dplyr-compatible function `janitor::clean_names()` which replaces the column names into a friendly format.